# How can I programmatically run arbitrary SQL statements against my Hibernate/HSQL database?

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa, jdbc

I'm looking for a way to programmatically execute arbitrary SQL commands against my DB.
(Hibernate, JPA, HSQL)
Query.createNativeQuery() doesn't work for things like CREATE TABLE.

Doing LOTS of searching, I thought I could use the Hibernate Session.doWork().
By using the deprecated Configuration.buildSesionFactory() seems to show that doWork won't work.
I get "use lacks privilege or object not found" for all the CREATE TABLE statements.

So, what other technique is there for executing arbitratry SQL statements?
There were some notes on using the underlying JDBC Statement, but I haven't figure out how to get a JDBC Connection object from Hibernate to try that.

Note that the hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create setting will NOT work for me, as I have ARRAY[] columns which it chokes on.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any problem executing a create table statement with a Hibernate native query. Just make sure to use `Query.executeUpdate()`, and not `Query.list()` or `Query.uniqueResult()`.

If it doesn't work, please tell us what happens when you execute it, and join the full stack trace of the exception and the SQL query you're executing.

Answer (score 0):

"use lacks privilege or object not found" in HSQL may mean anything, for example existence of a table with the same name. Error messages in HSQL are completely misleading. Try listing your tables using DatabaseMetadata - you have probably already created the table.